# Return a variable from field template

Tags: nodes, entities, theming

I want to return a "global" variable from a field template file

Assume I have a content type called "basic_page".  Basic Page has a field called "my_field".  In the template for basic page (`node--basic-page.tpl.php`), I render "my_field" by calling:

```
$fieldMarkup = drupal_render($content['field_my_field']);
```

In `field--field-my-field.tpl.php` I do whatever I need to do to return the field HTML / markup - no problems here.  But I want to return a variable to node--basic-page.tpl.php as well.  Is there a way to insert this variable into the node render array, or something of the sort?

I do not want to do this in a hook_preprocess function.  If there is no other option I will, but was hoping I can avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [template_preprocess_field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_field/8) in your template.php and add your variable there.

Then in your tpl.php you can easily access that variable and render that variable along with your markup.